# Detecting initial display

Tags: three.js

I'm loading eight 8192 x 4096 textures on init. Naturally there's a delay prior to  display as the textures load. Is there a way for me to detect when first display has taken place? With the example below, I'd like `onDocumentMouseDown` to fire only when I can see the textures - not while the screen is still blank as loading takes place.

```
function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(500, 100, 100);
    sphereGeometry.scale(-1, 1, 1);

    var renderList = ["DF_DC_DS", "DF_DC_LS", "DF_LC_DS", "DF_LC_LS", "LF_DC_DS", "LF_DC_LS", "LF_LC_DS", "LF_LC_LS"];

    for (var i = 0; i < renderList.length; i++) {

        var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "img/high-quality/" + renderList[i] + ".jpg", 
            function ( texture ) {
                textureLoadedCount++;
                if (textureLoadedCount == 8) {
                    allLoaded = true;   
                }
            }
        );
        texture.anisotropy = renderer.capabilities.getMaxAnisotropy();

        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );

        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( sphereGeometry, material );

        scene.add( mesh );

    }

    document.addEventListener( "mousedown", onDocumentMouseDown, false );

}
```

Comment: The mentioned delay in your app is mainly caused by two factors: The loading of your `JPG` textures from the backend and the corresponding decoding when textures are initially used on the GPU. The `onLoad()` event handler tells you the exact time when textures are loaded. Unfortunately, there is no equivalent event handler in order to detect the finished decoding process. You might want to used texture compression formats like `S3TC` or `ASTC` to entirely avoid this overhead.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Tried DDS, which does alleviate the decoding process, but further bloats the file load.